# DataSource Spring Security + Angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Как реализовать аутентификацию пользователя,если данные храняться в базе данных и в applicationContext.xml прописан dataSource:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Authentication-manager

```
<security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service
                    data-source-ref="dataSource"
                    users-by-username-query="SELECT eMail AS username, password, true AS enabled FROM user WHERE eMail=?"
                    authorities-by-username-query="SELECT eMail, role AS authority FROM user WHERE eMail=?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

На клиентской стороне работает Angular, забирая данные формы, он отправляет их постом на сервер,где этот запрос отлавливает контроллер  и передает данные сервису.

Контроллер FE LoginController.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Login').controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $state, $cookies, sha1, AuthenticationService) {

    $scope.login = function() {
        AuthenticationService.signIn($scope.username, $scope.password,
            function onSuccess(payload) {
                $state.go("dashboard");
            },
            function onError() {
                $state.go("login");
            }
        );
    }
    $scope.logout = function(){
        AuthenticationService.signOut(
            function onSuccess() {
                $state.go("login");
            }
        )
    }
});
```

Сервис FE AuthenticationService.js

```
'use strict';

app.factory('AuthenticationService', function (Network, $cookies) {
    return {

        signIn: function (username, password, onSuccess, onError) {
            Network.sendPost("/services/authentication/signIn",
                    {"login": username, "password": password},
                    onSuccess, onError);
        },

        signOut: function(onSuccess) {
            Network.sendGet("/services/authentication/signOut", {}, onSuccess);
        }
    };
});
```

BE контроллер AuthenticationContorller.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = Paths.SIGN_IN)
public final class AuthenticationController extends AbstractController<SignInEntity> {

    @Autowired
    SignInService signInService;

    @RequestMapping(value = Methods.SIGN_IN, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public final Result<SignInService.LoginStatus> signIn(@RequestBody final SignInEntity signInEntity) {
        return run(() -> signInService.checkLoginStatus(signInEntity.username, signInEntity.password));
    }
}
```

SignInService.java представляет из себя нечто следующее

```
@Service
public class SignInService extends AbstractService<SignInEntity>{
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public LoginStatus checkLoginStatus(String username, String password) {
            // Как сделать правильную проверку? Нужно ли реализовывать интерфейс Userdetails или не стоит?
    }

    public class LoginStatus {

       private final boolean loggedIn;
        private final String username;

        public LoginStatus(boolean loggedIn, String username) {
            this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
            this.username = username;
        }

        public boolean isLoggedIn() {
            return loggedIn;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно ли прописывать action в форме  /j_spring_security_check

```
<form  action="/j_spring_security_check"  method="post" name="loginForm">
```

и поля `name="j_username"`, `name="j_password"`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="j_username" id="exampleInputEmail1" ng-model="username">

<input type="password" class="form-control" name="j_password" id="exampleInputPassword1" ng-model="password">
```

или можно обойтись без этого, сделав по-другому?

Нужно ли реализововыть интерфейс `UserdetailService` в `SignInService` и  переопределять метод `loadUserByUsername(String username)` или можно как-то работать с `authenticationManager`, который через бин dataSource лезет в БД и дергает всю необходимую инфу.

P.S. Читал,что `UserdetailService` имплиментится, когда работаем с ORM,а я получается работаю с базой напрямую, с помощью jdbc. Если эта информация верная, то как реализовать проверку в сервисе используя бин dataSource?

Comment: Судя по тому что я вижу, вам вообще не нужен SpringSecurity. Если напрямую общаетесь в базой то и реализуйте запрос данных по тому что юзер предоставил прям в `checkLoginStatus()`